# Is there a way to make a Facebook share button in Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, facebook, dart, dart-js-interop

I'm making a quiz app in flutter and I'm nearly at the end of it, trying to make a facebook share button for them to be able to share their results in Facebook, and I can't find a way of making it work.
I couldn't find any pub that works on the web.
I tried to use the Facebook JS SDK but it gets too messy for my dart js knowledge, does anyone know a way to do this?
By now my best option is an embedded iframe and a static link... Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking as desperate as I was there's a link in the button Facebook creates for you, if you populate the HTML with the right og tags and dynamically change the link and launch it with url_launcher you can get through it

Answer (score 0):

My Plugin aims to help you with this:

https://pub.dev/packages/share_everywhere

It detects the platform and uses a list of social media icons you provide on a desktop.
And on mobile it uses standard share functionality.

Its a work in progress please let me know what you think and how i can improve.